# Auto populate Custom Memo ID field in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, infopath-form, auto-populate

I’m currently working on a SharePoint list and have been asked to develop a new form for when an Item is added to the list. I have the new form completed except for the final edit. I have a column Named “Memo ID”, on the new form this field needs to be automatically populated to the next Memo ID # when you open the form by clicking on add new item in the SharePoint list. For Example: Memo ID # of last item added to list is 202010. When the form opens up to add a new item The Memo ID # should already be 202011.

I’m new to SharePoint and InfoPath, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Receive data connection to the list, on Form Load retrieve the item with the largest number, increment that number by one and populate the field in the new form.

More details and step by step instructions [here](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/how-to-create-auto-increment-field-on-form-load-in-infopath/).

Comment: if that solves your issue, please mark the answer as explained in the [tour]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I’m still having trouble getting it to work. I opened up InfoPath > New > SharePoint List > Design Form. Data Connection wizard opens up and I paste the url to my SP site list. List has 4 columns, I select the MEMO ID field and set default value to 1 then publish. Next, created Receive data connection to the SP list while selecting both ID and MEMO ID Field. So far, do you see any place where I have made an error? Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used InfoPath in many years, since it is not used much anymore. There are many resources on the web though, from ten years ago, which will have what you are looking for. You may need to search a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll keep searching